# ExtJS/CSS--aligning tbar button right causes it to overflow until browser window is resized

Tags: html, css, extjs

I have a panel with top toolbar which contains one button pushed all the way to the right. Initially, the button overflows and gets cut off until the window is resized, then it automatically adjusts.

```
//toolbar inside panel initComponent
this.dockedItems = [{
      xtype:"toolbar",
      dock:"top",    
      style:"background-color:#d8d8d8;",      
      layout:{pack:"end"},
      items:[
        //"->",
        {
          xtype:"button", text:"Welcome", itemId:"userid",           
          menu: new Ext.menu.Menu({
            items:[{icon:"blah.png", scope:this,text:"Logout", itemId:"logout", handler:function(){this.fireEvent("logout");}}]
          })
        }

    }];
```

When the window is resized, regardless of how much horizontally/vertically, the button adjusts and all is fine after that. The issue is on initial load or before window is resized, the button is cut off. Once I resize window the button adjusts and as I gradually make the window smaller the button stays visible. This is  what I am essentially trying to achieve--keeping the button aligned/floating right regardless of the aspect ratio or resolution of the users screen.

Using the CSS left property with a hardcoded px value this problem does not occur. However, it gets cut off or does not show at all on screens with different resolutions.

So my question is how can i prevent the button from overflowing initially? Or is there another way I can align the button to the right, making it compatible for all screen resolutions?

ty

Comment: What happens if you remove the layout: {pack: end}, and just use '->' in the items?  That's what I've always done.  I haven't used layout on a toolbar before.  I just do '->' to send it all the way to the right.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that. Both pack:end and "->" cause the same issue. This is how I have always done it too but this is the first time this issue arose

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me, I can't replicate the bug.  The issue may be with that specific panel or perhaps some css behind the scenes.  To debug, maybe try taking that toolbar and putting it on a different panel.  Does the same issue occur?  If so, the problem lies elsewhere, if not, it may be something about your panel.

Comment: good call. It worked fine in a different toolbar. So i removed layout:"fit" from the original toolbar and then it worked.

Comment: Great, glad you got it working! :)